# Dynamic flow Input Lightning Component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I want to have a dynamic flow screen component where I can define what input it wants during the flow such as Text, Number, Date, DateTime etc. is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the out-of-the-box Flow Screen Input components will do this as described.

As of today, I think you have two general options:

1. Place one of each type of input on the screen, using conditional visibility rules to display just the one you want.
2. Build/Develop a custom Flow Screen component that more-or-less exposes the `lightning:input` component to Flow Screens, passing configuration values that determine the data type.

More info on Conditional Visibility in Flows:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screen_conditional_visibility.htm&type=5

Comment: Looks like I'll have to go down the lightning input route as the main issue is I want to have 5 fields per page so 5*types of data fields required would just be a mess to make.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the Lightning Input component from UnofficialSF.com, which has a number of input formats:  https://unofficialsf.com/lightninginput/

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thanks for contributing. Be sure to take the SFSE [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look around the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) to determine more ways to contribute.